# Import Data from SQL Server to a Formatted Excel File

Tags: sql-server, excel

this will be my last question regarding my project that I have been working on, I have a table in my SQL server with the following columns:

```
[DATE], [SOURCE], [DESTINATION], [REFERENCE#], [ITEMCODE], [DESCRIPTION],
[UM], [PRICE], [QTY], [AMOUNT], [MFGDATE], [EXPDATE], [LOT#], [TRANS], [CONSIGNOR], [DRDATE]
```

Now I want to generate a excel file from that table that will be depends on this:

```
1. Date Range
2. Source
3. Destination
4. Consignor
5. Trans
```

and will generate a excel file like this:

```
HEADER

Consignor
ITEM CODE    |     DESCRIPTION    |   UM   |   DATE   |   DATE   |...| TOTAL
'itemcode'   |     'description'  |   'um' |    qty   |   qty    |...|'total'
------------TOTAL--------------------------|  'total' | 'total'  |...|'total'
```

is it possible to generate that kind of report?

Comment: Would you expect your report in excel to be in a single column ?

Comment: @MJoy, no, different column for each, ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, UM, DATE...

Comment: if you are expecting one row column (total) to span the first three columns then no. This is a report writer question, not database, though the associate product SSRS could do it. You could construct a data set that creates all this but you are really barking up the wrong tree trying to do it. Look at SSRS or some other report writer.

Comment: You can import data into Power Pivot from SQL Server. After that, building your report is easy.